# XMLHttpRequest Request URI too large (414)

Tags: uri, xmlhttprequest

Well I hoped everything would work fine finally. But of course it doesn't. The new problem is the following message:

> Request-URI Too Large
>  The requested URL's length exceeds the
>   capacity limit for this server.

My fear is that I have to find another method of transmitting the data or is a solution possible?

Code of XHR function:

```
function makeXHR(recordData)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 var rowData = "?q=" + recordData;

 xmlhttp.open("POST", "insertRowData.php"+rowData, true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",rowData.length); 
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
 {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
  {
   alert("Records were saved successfully!");
  }
 }

 xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should POST `rowData` in the request body via the `send` method. So, instead of posting to `"insertRowData.php" + rowData`, POST to `"insertRowData.php"` and pass the data in `rowData` to `send`.

I suspect that your `rowData` is a query string with the question mark. If that is the case, then the message body is simply `rowData` *without* the prepended question mark.

**EDIT:** Something like this should work:

```
var body = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(recordData);
xmlhttp.open("POST", "insertRowData.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = // ...
xmlhttp.send(body);
```

Comment: hi. i tried your code but now i dont get the data in my php script:

PHP:

$q = $_GET["q"];
 
echo $q;

Comment: @usurper: You need to use the `$_POST` superglobal array: `$q = $_POST['q']; echo htmlspecialchars($q);`

Comment: hmmm. this is what i got after using $q = $_POST['q'];: 

Undefined variable: q